# VSTO Compile Error in Hidden Module: Clipboard when using Excel.Range get_Range

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I have been working up an Add-In to process data out of Excel files sitting in a directory. My program has run successfully in production under a number of scenarios, so I know my code is generally solid. Until now, I have been reading just the first 'sheet' of the Excel file.

I have been working on a feature that will 'crawl' through the entire Workbook by doing a foreach loop through the `Worksheets` object. The process works fine for the most part, but on occasion when I change sheets I get the message popup: `Compile Error in Hidden Module: Clipboard`. I do not at any point call or write anything to the clipboard. I have restarted my machine to clear memory and still get the message.

On breakpoint checks, I get the message after calling `Excel.Range oRng = thisExcel.xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1").SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);` - at which point it throws that `Complile Error` message twice (on the same line), and then continues on. It does not cause the program to fail - and if I keep clicking 'Okay' it will proceed to the end and give me my output.

In my code, `oRng` is a local variable in a function different from the process that sets a new `ActiveSheet`, so it is null until `get_Range` is called.

This doesn't happen ever when I read only 1 sheet per Workbook, and it will still run to the end - just throws this message and will not proceed until it is dismissed. I'm using VSTO 2010.

Is there a problem with my use of `get_Range`? I can share more code on request if that will help shed more light.

**UPDATE:**

Tried a suggestion that I clear Clipboard. When I try `Clipboard.Clear()`, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out `Compile Error in Hidden Module: Clipboard` was a message for some specific macros in a few of the workbooks provided to me. It ran all kinds of problems in Excel 2010. But when tested against Excel 2013, there was no problem.